# BATCH FILE - IF Exists & Output Error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

INFO: assets.txt contains a list of cpu names which I can connect to over the network.

I need to copy this new .exe to well over 200+ computers and figured i could use the c$ admin share. This is really the only way I can do this without going to workstations individually or remoting in one by one.

This script works without the 'if exists' however I need to check if the directory exists before attempting the copy. I don't understand why it isn't working. I am also running this script using my domain administrative account.

```
@echo off
REM Pull Computer Asset Tags from file
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (assets.txt) do (
    echo Start Processing %%A
    REM Temporarily set file path for existence check
    set file=\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Intouch2\Intouch2ca.exe
    if EXIST "%file%" (
        REM Rename old .exe 
        ren "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Intouch2\Intouch2ca.exe" "Intouch2ca.bak"

        REM copy new .exe from server to cpu asset
        xcopy "\\server\my dir\management\it\software\Intouch Upgrade\Intouch2ca.exe" "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Intouch2\" /Y 
        echo END Processing %%A
        echo.
        echo ------------------------------------------------------------
        echo.
    )
)
```

I also haven't been able to get the error output to a log file.
I have tried this but it isnt exactly what I would like.

`xcopy "\\server\my dir\management\it\software\Intouch Upgrade\Intouch2ca.exe" "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Intouch2\" /Y 1>>errors.log 2>&1`

How can I pretty that up so it only shows errors and lists the `%%A` where the error occured?

Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: Where is the error message coming from?  What error is it?

Comment: I want to be able to catch errors from the file copy. Your solution works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, in your case, `file` is being changed **within** the block, so the value `cmd` uses is its initial value when the entire `for` is parsed.

Solution 1: use `\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Intouch2\Intouch2ca.exe` in place of `%file%`

Solution 2: start your batch with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` on a separate line after the `@echo off`, then use `!file!` in place of `%var%`

Solution 3: call an internal routine to use the mofified value as `%file%`

Solution 4: Create the directory regardless. `MD newname 2>nul` will silently create a new directory if it doesn't already exist

Answer (score 2):

An error on a copy will set an errorlevel and you can write a custom error message.

```
copy "\\server\my dir\management\it\software\Intouch Upgrade\Intouch2ca.exe" "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Intouch2\" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 >> errors.txt echo "Error in %%A"
```